# How to read many pickle files and store them in a database?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to combine 4,30,000 **pickle files** each of which contains 2 lists of lists.

example:

Lemmas = [['pañcan'], ['ratna'], ['mukhya'], ['ca', 'uparatna', 'catuṣṭaya']]

Morphological_class = [['41'], ['41'], ['41'], ['2', '3', '31']]

I want to create a DB file(sqlite) which contains 2 columns in which one column is Lemmas[i][j] and the other column is Morphological_class[i][j]

for the above example my database will look like :

Lemma     Morphological

pañcan     41

ratna      41

mukhya     41

ca         2

uparatna   3

catuṣṭaya  31

What is the fastest way to achieve this ? I have used sqlite3 in python and used for loops to iterate through each pickle and store it. It is taking a lot of time this way.

Total file size = 2.3GB

Comment: Handling 2.3GB of data will need some time. Ensure that you enclose the database writing in a single transaction.

Comment: @MichaelButscher generally good advice, but I doubt that is the bottle-neck, rather, it is the loading and deserializing of 4million + pickles.

Comment: yes @juanpa.arrivillaga  My doubt is that is it more efficient to store entries in the database as I iterate through the list or better to store it in a pandas dataframe and then convert it to a DB file at the end.

Comment: @AnandMooga maybe? I will say, I suspect it is your I/O with the pickle files + deserialization that is the bottleneck. Not sure why `pandas` would help here either. Why not just a list of tuples? But you should probably provide your actual code, or else one can only speculate.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I also think so but if the data is available as pickle files the unpickling can't be avoided